# PyCharm often fails to restore its main window maximised

Tags: pycharm

I generally work with maximised applications to increase screen real estate, and periodically close and reopen IDE projects to clear the undo/redo stack.  Since the last PyCharm update, I've been finding that when I reopen a project, the main window fails to retain its previous maximised state.  It also resizes the project tool window.  It's a minor annoyance, and doesn't prevent me from working, but I'd like to fix it.

One thought.  I'm also using the settings repository plugin to share settings across multiple PCs, for IntelliJ, PyCharm and Android Studio.  Maybe the settings are getting confused, and clearing out the settings Git repo would fix this?  But I don't want to try this before getting advice from the community.

- PyCharm 2019.2.3 (latest)
- Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

I've seen JetBrains products doing this before, but it's gone away with software updates.  I've done several Google and StackOverflow searches, but it's all for unrelated issues.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the record, this appears to have fixed the problem:

1. Uninstalled PyCharm.
2. Deleted local directory ~/.PyCharmCE2019.2.
3. Reinstalled PyCharm with new settings Git repository.

UPDATE - Spoke too soon, the issue is still occurring, though it seems to happen when I close and reopen the project, and not when I close and reopen PyCharm itself.